# Python filter duplicates from command line

Tags: python, filter, duplicates

Is it possible in python handle this situation:

```
./test.py foo bar foobar foo bar
```

and get next output:

```
foo bar foobar
```

in order of which the arguments appear.

Comment: `list(set(sys.argv[1:]]))`

Comment: @JDong, sets are unordered

Comment: Yea I saw that, but he never specified order was required. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @JDong updated specifying order!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this it gives expected output as showing only the unique value passed to the file

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
loc_args = sys.argv[1:]
if loc_args:
   print ' '.join(set(loc_args))
```

Input:

```
 ./test.py foo bar foobar foo bar
```

Output:

```
foo bar foobar
```

**Edit:** I missed point that says we need to maintain order as well so here is the final solutions

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

loc_args = sys.argv[1:]
if loc_args:
    print ' '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(loc_args).keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on sets that maintains order:

```
import sys

seen=set()
print ' '.join([x for x in sys.argv[1:] if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))])
```

Or same thing, more verbosely:

```
import sys

seen=set()
uniqs=[]
for e in sys.argv[1:]:
    if e not in seen:
        uniqs.append(e)
        seen.add(e)

print ' '.join(uniqs)
```